# Thickbox (jQuery) breaking prototype in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, thickbox

I'm creating my first rails app, and using the standard prototype library for some effects. I recently brought in Thickbox which is breaking all of the previous effects.

I know there is a no conflict method for jQuery but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it?

Should I just do a find/replace for $ in the jquery and thickbox .js files?

Thanks!
-Elliot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I just do a find/replace for $
>   in the jquery and thickbox .js files?

**NO !**

You can check out the jQuery docs for details on [using noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).